# scp to remote server with sudo

Tags: command-line, security, sudo, scp

I have a file on server A (which is behind a NAT so not directly addressable). The file needs to be copied to server B in a directory restricted to root. I have an account on server B with sudo privileges. What is the syntax for the scp command?

Comment: I have answered on [another posting](http://superuser.com/a/1120455/559952) how you can customize scp do the sudo for you directly. This is similar to what WinSCP does.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

First, you need to copy the file to a place where you have write access without sudo,

```
scp yourfile serverb:
```

Then move the file using sudo

```
ssh serverb sudo mv yourfile /path/to/the/destination
```

If you do not have a writable place, make a temporary dir with write permission for your user.

```
ssh serverb sudo mkdir tempdir && sudo chmod 777 tempdir
scp yourfile serverb:tempdir
ssh serverb mv tempdir/yourfile /path/to/the/destination
```

Comment: /tmp is a good place for writing temporary files that (usually) all users have access to.

Comment: @Doug: Note that /tmp could be in RAM or in / mounting point, and not necessarily large enough to host big files.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, `chmod 777` is usually the wrong way to do it.  Consider what could happen if somebody else was logged in and knew you were about to run this code.

Comment: `ssh sudo` doesn't work for me -- complains "no tty present and no askpass program specified"?

Comment: @RossPresser sorry for late answer, but you either need to setup passwordless sudo on `serverb` or you need to `ssh serverb` separately, then run `sudo ...` after logged in.

Comment: @RossPresser it worked for me with the additional option -t to send pseudo-tty.

Answer (score 113):

With SCP, you have to do in two steps, however, you can do it in one with rsync as follows:

```
rsync --rsync-path="sudo rsync" <LOCALFILE> USER@SERVER2:/root
```

<sup>Note: This does require `NOPASSWD` sudo configuration. If you have to enter the password for sudo, then the two step way is needed.</sup>

To copy directory, you need to add `-r` parameter. And `-v` for verbose output.

---

To use above method with credentials, you need to add them into your `~/.ssh/config` file, e.g.

```
Host SERVER2
  HostName server2.example.colm
  User USER
  #IdentityFile ~/.ssh/custom_key.pem
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Error `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` fixed by 
`-e "ssh -tt"`.

Comment: @mj41 With `-e "ssh -tt"`, I get `protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?`. Any hints on how to fix that?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Not all systems have `rsync`: `sudo: rsync: command not found` so scp is still more universal way.

Answer (score 22):

You can use ssh and tar to work around this:

```
ssh -t host 'sudo -v'
ssh -C host 'cd /; sudo tar cf - path/to/file/or/dir' | tar xpsf - --preserve
```

This first updates your sudo timestamp (asking for a password if necessary, which requires a tty (`ssh -t`)), and then uses sudo to create a tarball remotely and extract it locally.

"tar" on RedHat 5 requires the "--preserve" options to come after the "xpsf -" command.

Comment: Just a note: if you get `tar: Invalid replacement string`, removing `-s` in the seems to fix it (not sure what you need the `s` for anyway).  Many thanks; this is awesome.

Comment: This would require `tty_tickets` to be disabled, correct?

Comment: @JacobBudin yes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use sftp with sudo command, for instance:

```
sftp -s 'sudo -u REMOTE_SUDO_USER /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server' REMOTE_USER@HOST
```

Comment: This and the rsync methods are probably the most direct way of doing it in one step. It is unfortunate that the scp task in ant does not support it. You can set it to use sftp, but you cannot modify the remote sub-program. Note that the sub-program will be different depending on the type of server (solaris might be different).

Comment: I don't see where in this solution you actually specify the local file to be transferred to the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to type password for sudo every-time, you can save it to a file:

```
echo "Enter password: "; read -s password; echo $password > password_file
```

and then send it along with the source file.

```
cat password_file source_file | ssh remote_host 'sudo -S sponge target_file'
```

You can use `tee` instead of `sponge` if you don’t have moreutils.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to copy the file to a place where you have write access without sudo,
You can do the following two steps.

Step 1:
`scp filename newserver`

Step 2:
`ssh newserver sudo mv filename /path/to/the/destination`

for more information [read scp tutorial](https://linux4one.com/how-to-use-scp-command-to-transfer-files-folders-in-linux/)

Answer (score -2):

```
current server $ sudo scp username@server:source/path/filename /tmp/
```

It will copy specific file from source to /tmp/ in current server

Comment: It will execute the sudo locally, giving you no elevated privileges remotely.

Comment: scp won't probably connect, because it will reads the key of root