# Sudo and perform scp

Tags: sudo, scp

Possible duplicate of [scp to remote server with sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo)

I'm facing the following issue:

- A folder (with sub-folders) with files belonging to `usr1:usr1`
- I login with another user `usr2`
- `usr2` can do `sudo -u usr1`
- How can I copy the whole folder to another Linux box over ssh?

I tried the following with no success:

```
sudo -u usr1 tar cf - * |  ssh  usr2@host 'cd /tmp/dump;  sudo -u usr1 tar xf -'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have answered on [another posting](http://superuser.com/a/1120455/559952) how you can customize scp do the sudo for you directly. This is similar to what WinSCP does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `scp` as mentioned in the link you provided, but with the `-r` flag added to the command. The `-r` means recursive, so it repeats the `scp` command for every file and/or folder it finds in that particular folder.

> scp -r yourfolder name@host:targetfolder

Comment: it won't work because of permission. virtually -1 to you )

Answer (score 0):

On the host containing the folder to be copied, run this:

```
sudo -u usr1 scp -r folder-to-copy usr2@host:/tmp/dump/.
```