# scp from remote server with pmrun

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer, scp

I want to copy file/s from remote server to central server and then to localhost

The way I access is from localhost I connect to central server using SSH

Then I connect to required remote server using pmrun as 
pmrun -h jmjgv12643 user001

user001 is privilged user where as I am not.

I need to copy files from jmjgv12643 to central server and then back to localhost.

How can I do that, If more explanation is needed, Please let me know.

Comment: If the problem is one of permissions then [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo) might help. Otherwise, does the problem also arrive when connecting with the remote computer's IP address rather than its name?

Comment: Any comment on the above?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use `scp` with `pmrun`. I am not sure how it works with the hostname widget (`-h`), but your scenario should work as follows:

**1** Connect to central server with SSH, and from the central server, use the `pmrun` command in the following way to copy files from the remote server over to the central one:

```
pmrun -h scp user001@jmjgv12643:/path/to/file/to/copy local_file_or_directory
```

**2** Once the files are on the central server you can just use plain `scp` to copy them. From your **local** machine, you can use the following command to copy files from your central server to localhost:

```
scp user@central:/path/to/file/to/copy local_file_or_directory
```

Here **user** is the user you use to log into central server (**central**).
**local_file_or_directory** is the destination where you want your files to be copied.

Comment: `pmrun -h scp user001@jmjgv12643:/path/to/file/to/copy local_file_or_directory` does not work

it says `pmrun5.5.2 (044): 5033 Cannot resolve hostname (scp)`

Comment: @AkhilJain this is happening because scp cannot resolve the hostname that pmrun knows.. can you try to connect by using IP address and not hostname?